# brute force password with words and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing this science fair project for school: http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/CompSci_p046.shtml#summary

The project gives you base program that guesses the passwords that you input into the program and uses a different methods to guess it. Part of the project is to come up with new algorithms to add to the program. One of the methods is using long list of common passwords to match the given password and another is a simple lock-dial simulation of numbers up to 8 digits. I was wondering if there was a way two combine those to so it checks a word in the list plus the number dial behind the word. How to write a simple code to do that?

**What I'm really asking for is for someone to help me write a new method that goes through the word list and add a number dial (brute force with numbers) after the word, then check to see if that's the password inputed.**

Original program and word list can be downloaded here: http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/CompSci_p046.shtml#materials

This is the number dial simulation the program uses

```
def search_method_1(num_digits):
    global totalguesses
    result = False
    a=0
    #num_digits = 3    # How many digits to try. 1 = 0 to 9, 2 = 00 to 99, etc.
    starttime = time.time()
    tests = 0
    still_searching = True
    print("Using method 1 and searching for "+str(num_digits)+" digit numbers.")
    while still_searching and a<(10**num_digits):
        ourguess = leading_zeroes(a,num_digits)
        tests = tests + 1
        totalguesses = totalguesses + 1
        if (check_userpass(which_password, ourguess)):
            print ("Success! Password "+str(which_password)+" is " + ourguess)
            still_searching = False   # we can stop now - we found it!
            result = True
        else:
            print ("Darn. " + ourguess + " is NOT the password.")
        a=a+1

    seconds = time.time()-starttime
    report_search_time(tests, seconds)
    return result
```

This is the code that runs through the word list:

```
def search_method_3(file_name):
    global totalguesses
    result = False

# Start by reading the list of words into a Python list
f = open(file_name)
words = f.readlines()
f.close
# We need to know how many there are
number_of_words = len(words)
print("Using method 3 with "+str(number_of_words)+" in the list")

## Depending on the file system, there may be extra characters before
## or after the words. 
for i in range(0, number_of_words):
    words[i] = cleanup(words[i])

# Let's try each one as the password and see what happens
starttime = time.time()
tests = 0
still_searching = True
word1count = 0           # Which word we'll try next

while still_searching:
    ourguess_pass = words[word1count]
    #print("Guessing: "+ourguess_pass)
    # Try it the way it is in the word list
    if (check_userpass(which_password, ourguess_pass)):
        print ("Success! Password "+str(which_password)+" is " + ourguess_pass)
        still_searching = False   # we can stop now - we found it!
        result = True
    #else:
        #print ("Darn. " + ourguess_pass + " is NOT the password.")
    tests = tests + 1
    totalguesses = totalguesses + 1
    # Now let's try it with the first letter capitalized
    if still_searching:
        ourguess_pass = Cap(ourguess_pass)
        #print("Guessing: "+ourguess_pass)
        if (check_userpass(which_password, ourguess_pass)):
            print ("Success! Password "+str(which_password)+" is " + ourguess_pass)
            still_searching = False   # we can stop now - we found it!
            result = True
        #else:
            #print ("Darn. " + ourguess_pass + " is NOT the password.")
        tests = tests + 1
        totalguesses = totalguesses + 1

    word1count = word1count + 1
    if (word1count >=  number_of_words):
        still_searching = False

seconds = time.time()-starttime
report_search_time(tests, seconds)
return result
```

Comment: Its nice that you're working on code, but this post is WAY too big and I'm not even sure what the question is. You need to edit this down to a clear, singular question.

Comment: Sorry bout that ill fix it right now

Comment: @Citation Please post the code only relevant problem, not whole code.

Comment: Are you asking someone else to write a program for you? Even then it's not completely clear what the requirements of the program would be.

Comment: Not the whole program, just a new function that goes through the wordlist and adds numbers behind each word using a number based brute force method.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I don't really know what I'm doing I new to the whole coding community and first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you... but here's what I suggest: look at the code that combines multiple words separated by punctuation. And then look at the code that tries "dial" combinations. Instead of combining multiple words, you can combine a word and a dial combination. And then the next dial combo, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question to mean that you want to interlace the numeric guesses with the alphabetic guesses.

One problem you are facing is that the logic that keeps time and the logic that checks if the password is correct is mixed in with the logic that generates guesses. You might want to use generators to break out the "guess generation" into separate functions.

```
from itertools import izip

def numerical_guess():
    current_guess = 0
    while True:
        yield current_guess
        current_guess += 1

def dictionary_guess():
     for word in {'apple', 'banana', 'orange'}:
          yield word

for guess in izip(numerical_guess(), dictionary_guess()):
    if guess == password:
         print "Got it!"
    else:
         print "Not it!"
```

There are some things you will have to think about, such as what if one generator runs out before the other one.

You mention that you don't know enough to understand this level of code, but I don't see anything so complicated with the code. Your posted code only uses the most basic control structures of python so I wonder if this post will even be helpful for you. Maybe you could go through the code line by line and mention any part of the code that is confusing for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll be going through the code today and tomorrow hope you could stay to help.